# CRM 2013 - linq query to get accounts for a specific owner

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm

I need to get all the account records assigned to the system user. This linq query is not working. What am I doing wrong?
    `

```
var accts = from a in xrm.AccountSet
   where a.OwningUser == new CrmEntityReference(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName,  new Guid("<systemUserGuid>"))
   select a;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
ar accts = from a in xrm.AccountSet
   where a.OwnerId.Id == new Guid("<systemUserGuid>")
   select a;
```